# O formato "date" desaparece depois que uso a função "group_by" seguida de "summarise (mean())" no R

Tags: r, group-by, lubridate

Estou trabalhando com seguinte base de dados sobre temperaturas globais:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nSwP3Y0V7gncbnG_DccNhrTRxmUNqMqa

Eu importo os dados com a função `import()` do pacote `rio` e gravo no objeto `df`.

```
df<-rio::import("TemperaturasGlobais.csv")

head(df)

 dt AverageTemperature AverageTemperatureUncertainty   City Country Latitude Longitude
1 1743-11-01              6.068                         1.737 Ã…rhus Denmark   57.05N    10.33E
2 1743-12-01                 NA                            NA Ã…rhus Denmark   57.05N    10.33E
3 1744-01-01                 NA                            NA Ã…rhus Denmark   57.05N    10.33E
4 1744-02-01                 NA                            NA Ã…rhus Denmark   57.05N    10.33E
5 1744-03-01                 NA                            NA Ã…rhus Denmark   57.05N    10.33E
6 1744-04-01              5.788                         3.624 Ã…rhus Denmark   57.05N    10.33E
```

No entanto, a coluna `dt` (referente à data) vem no formato `character`.

```
str(df)

'data.frame':   8599212 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ dt                           : chr  "1743-11-01" "1743-12-01" "1744-01-01" "1744-02-01" ...
 $ AverageTemperature           : num  6.07 NA NA NA NA ...
 $ AverageTemperatureUncertainty: num  1.74 NA NA NA NA ...
 $ City                         : chr  "Ã…rhus" "Ã…rhus" "Ã…rhus" "Ã…rhus" ...
 $ Country                      : chr  "Denmark" "Denmark" "Denmark" "Denmark" ...
 $ Latitude                     : chr  "57.05N" "57.05N" "57.05N" "57.05N" ...
 $ Longitude                    : chr  "10.33E" "10.33E" "10.33E" "10.33E" ...
```

Então, aplico a função `ymd()` do lubridate para convertê-la para o formato `date` e gravo no objeto `df2`.

```
df2<-df %>% 
  mutate(dt=ymd(dt))

head(df2)

dt AverageTemperature AverageTemperatureUncertainty   City Country Latitude Longitude
1 1743-11-01              6.068                         1.737 Ã…rhus Denmark   57.05N    10.33E
2 1743-12-01                 NA                            NA Ã…rhus Denmark   57.05N    10.33E
3 1744-01-01                 NA                            NA Ã…rhus Denmark   57.05N    10.33E
4 1744-02-01                 NA                            NA Ã…rhus Denmark   57.05N    10.33E
5 1744-03-01                 NA                            NA Ã…rhus Denmark   57.05N    10.33E
6 1744-04-01              5.788                         3.624 Ã…rhus Denmark   57.05N    10.33E
```

Confiro, e vejo que funcionou. A coluna "dt" agora está no formato "date"

```
str(df2)

'data.frame':   8599212 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ dt                           : Date, format: "1743-11-01" "1743-12-01" "1744-01-01" "1744-02-01" ...
 $ AverageTemperature           : num  6.07 NA NA NA NA ...
 $ AverageTemperatureUncertainty: num  1.74 NA NA NA NA ...
 $ City                         : chr  "Ã…rhus" "Ã…rhus" "Ã…rhus" "Ã…rhus" ...
 $ Country                      : chr  "Denmark" "Denmark" "Denmark" "Denmark" ...
 $ Latitude                     : chr  "57.05N" "57.05N" "57.05N" "57.05N" ...
 $ Longitude                    : chr  "10.33E" "10.33E" "10.33E" "10.33E" ...
```

O problema vem agora: eu faço o agrupamento (`group_by`) **por ANO**, filtro apenas para o país `Brazil`, e solicito a média anual `summarise (mean())` com a remoção dos valores faltantes (`na.rm = T`).

```
df3<-df2 %>% 
  group_by(ano=year(dt)) %>% 
  filter(Country=="Brazil") %>% 
  summarise(media.anual=mean(AverageTemperature, na.rm = T))
```

A saída é uma tibble cuja coluna `dt` não está mais no formato `date`.

```
# A tibble: 190 x 2
     ano media.anual
   <dbl>       <dbl>
 1  1824        26.5
 2  1825        26.5
 3  1826        26.4
 4  1827        26.7
 5  1828        26.1
 6  1829        26.0
 7  1830       NaN  
 8  1831       NaN  
 9  1832        20.5
10  1833        21.4
# ... with 180 more rows


str(df3)

tibble [190 x 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ ano        : num [1:190] 1824 1825 1826 1827 1828 ...
 $ media.anual: num [1:190] 26.5 26.5 26.4 26.7 26.1 ...
```

Daí, são 3 as minhas dúvidas:

1. Por que depois de utilizar a função do `group_by`+`summarise(mean())` o resultado desfaz a formatação de `date` que consegui anteriormente?
2. Como faço para essa tibble ficar no formato `date`?
3. Uma curiosidade: por que o valores faltantes aparecem na tibble `df3` como `NaN` e não como `NA`? O que significa esse `NaN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Por definição, a função `year` do pacote `lubridate` retorna um valor numérico. Este é o motivo para a coluna `dt` ser `double` e não um `date`.

```
x <- ymd("2012-03-26")
    
is.numeric(year(x))
## [1] TRUE    

is.Date(year(x))
## [1] FALSE
```

2. No `R`, uma data é, na imensa maioria das vezes, composta por ano, mês, dia, hora, minuto e segundo. Ou seja, a saída aqui é criar um dia e mês fictício para poder ter uma data no programa. Minha maneira preferida é referenciar o valor do ano para primeiro de janeiro:

```
ano <- c(2003, 2010, 2015)

data <- ymd(paste(ano, 1, 1, sep = "-"))

is.Date(data)
## [1] TRUE
```

No teu caso específico, o código

```
df3<-df2 %>% 
  group_by(ano = year(dt)) %>% 
  filter(Country == "Brazil") %>% 
  summarise(media.anual = mean(AverageTemperature, na.rm = T))
  mutate(ano = ymd(paste(anos, 1, 1, sep = "-")))
```

deve funcionar.

3. `NaN` é a sigla para *Not a Number*. Isso ocorre porque o `R` não conseguiu representar computacionalmente o resultado da operação pedida. O caso mais clássico disso é tentar dividir 0 por 0:

```
0/0
## [1] NaN
```

A melhor maneira de tentar entender porque isso está acontecendo com os teus dados é olhando diretamente eles, sem fazer operação alguma. Abaixo eu listo todas os valores de `AverageTemperature` para `Brazil` em 1830:

```
df2 %>% 
    group_by(ano=year(dt)) %>% 
    filter(Country=="Brazil") %>% 
    filter(ano == 1830) %>%
    print(n = Inf)

## # A tibble: 48 x 8
## # Groups:   ano [1]
##    dt         AverageTemperat… AverageTemperat… City  Country Latitude Longitude
##    <date>                <dbl>            <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>    
##  1 1830-01-01               NA               NA Boa … Brazil  2.41N    60.27W   
##  2 1830-02-01               NA               NA Boa … Brazil  2.41N    60.27W   
##  3 1830-03-01               NA               NA Boa … Brazil  2.41N    60.27W   
##  4 1830-04-01               NA               NA Boa … Brazil  2.41N    60.27W   
##  5 1830-05-01               NA               NA Boa … Brazil  2.41N    60.27W   
##  6 1830-06-01               NA               NA Boa … Brazil  2.41N    60.27W   
##  7 1830-07-01               NA               NA Boa … Brazil  2.41N    60.27W   
##  8 1830-08-01               NA               NA Boa … Brazil  2.41N    60.27W   
##  9 1830-09-01               NA               NA Boa … Brazil  2.41N    60.27W   
## 10 1830-10-01               NA               NA Boa … Brazil  2.41N    60.27W   
## 11 1830-11-01               NA               NA Boa … Brazil  2.41N    60.27W   
## 12 1830-12-01               NA               NA Boa … Brazil  2.41N    60.27W   
## 13 1830-01-01               NA               NA Maca… Brazil  0.80N    50.63W   
## 14 1830-02-01               NA               NA Maca… Brazil  0.80N    50.63W   
## 15 1830-03-01               NA               NA Maca… Brazil  0.80N    50.63W   
## 16 1830-04-01               NA               NA Maca… Brazil  0.80N    50.63W   
## 17 1830-05-01               NA               NA Maca… Brazil  0.80N    50.63W   
## 18 1830-06-01               NA               NA Maca… Brazil  0.80N    50.63W   
## 19 1830-07-01               NA               NA Maca… Brazil  0.80N    50.63W   
## 20 1830-08-01               NA               NA Maca… Brazil  0.80N    50.63W   
## 21 1830-09-01               NA               NA Maca… Brazil  0.80N    50.63W   
## 22 1830-10-01               NA               NA Maca… Brazil  0.80N    50.63W   
## 23 1830-11-01               NA               NA Maca… Brazil  0.80N    50.63W   
## 24 1830-12-01               NA               NA Maca… Brazil  0.80N    50.63W   
## 25 1830-01-01               NA               NA Mana… Brazil  2.41S    60.27W   
## 26 1830-02-01               NA               NA Mana… Brazil  2.41S    60.27W   
## 27 1830-03-01               NA               NA Mana… Brazil  2.41S    60.27W   
## 28 1830-04-01               NA               NA Mana… Brazil  2.41S    60.27W   
## 29 1830-05-01               NA               NA Mana… Brazil  2.41S    60.27W   
## 30 1830-06-01               NA               NA Mana… Brazil  2.41S    60.27W   
## 31 1830-07-01               NA               NA Mana… Brazil  2.41S    60.27W   
## 32 1830-08-01               NA               NA Mana… Brazil  2.41S    60.27W   
## 33 1830-09-01               NA               NA Mana… Brazil  2.41S    60.27W   
## 34 1830-10-01               NA               NA Mana… Brazil  2.41S    60.27W   
## 35 1830-11-01               NA               NA Mana… Brazil  2.41S    60.27W   
## 36 1830-12-01               NA               NA Mana… Brazil  2.41S    60.27W   
## 37 1830-01-01               NA               NA Sant… Brazil  2.41S    55.45W   
## 38 1830-02-01               NA               NA Sant… Brazil  2.41S    55.45W   
## 39 1830-03-01               NA               NA Sant… Brazil  2.41S    55.45W   
## 40 1830-04-01               NA               NA Sant… Brazil  2.41S    55.45W   
## 41 1830-05-01               NA               NA Sant… Brazil  2.41S    55.45W   
## 42 1830-06-01               NA               NA Sant… Brazil  2.41S    55.45W   
## 43 1830-07-01               NA               NA Sant… Brazil  2.41S    55.45W   
## 44 1830-08-01               NA               NA Sant… Brazil  2.41S    55.45W   
## 45 1830-09-01               NA               NA Sant… Brazil  2.41S    55.45W   
## 46 1830-10-01               NA               NA Sant… Brazil  2.41S    55.45W   
## 47 1830-11-01               NA               NA Sant… Brazil  2.41S    55.45W   
## 48 1830-12-01               NA               NA Sant… Brazil  2.41S    55.45W   
## # … with 1 more variable: ano <dbl>
```

Note que não existe nenhum valor de temperatura registrado para o Brasil em 1830. Se tu for calcular a média destes valores, retirando o que for `NA`, não vai sobrar nenhuma observação. Portanto, é gerada uma indeterminação, tornando impossível calcular a média o Brasil neste ano específico. Pode checar que o mesmo vale para 1831.